# Calculating table row cells horizontaly. How?

Tags: javascript, html

I am aware of how to do it in JQuery but would like to see a solution in pure java script.

I have the following working code but I am having a **hard time calculating row cells horizontally**.

Currently, when I type in a blue quantity cell, the `function calculateColumnTotals()` adds up every cell in columns MAT, LAB & EQP. It then outputs the total for each column at their respective bottoms.

The challenge

**When I type in a blue quantity cell**, I need to **first call the** `function calculateRowTotals(inputQuantity, inputQuantityValue, callback)` to calculate the following...

1. MAT = QTY * $/EA
2. LAB = QTY * $/EA
3. EQP = QTY * $/EA
4. TTL = MAT + LAB + EQP

..**and only then**, call `function calculateColumnTotals()` to add up the columns.

Any help would be greatly apreciated.

```js
// Local Scripts begin here.

// reference to table
var tableLineItems = document.getElementById('tableLineItems');

// global variables...
var materialColumnTotal = 0;
var laborColumnTotal = 0;
var equipmentColumnTotal = 0;
var grandTotal = 0;

// Create global keyupTimer1 outside keyup scope.
var keyupTimer1;

// Call querySelectorAll() on all elements with a specific class, then use forEach() to iterate on them:
document.querySelectorAll('.input-quantity').forEach(cell => {
  // add event listeners...
  cell.addEventListener('keyup', event => {

    console.log('keyup event works.');

    if (keyupTimer1) {
      // Reset keyupTimer1 and abort function call.
      clearTimeout(keyupTimer1);
    }
    // Set keyupTimer1 to tick in 1 second for 1 seconds then call function and stop.
    keyupTimer1 = setTimeout(function (event) {
      // debug
      console.log('keyupTimer1 works.');

      var inputQuantity = cell;
      var inputQuantityValue = parseFloat(cell.innerText);

      // debug - QTY
      console.log('cellInnerTextQuantity: ', inputQuantityValue);

      // handle keyup event
      calculateRowTotals(inputQuantity, inputQuantityValue, calculateColumnTotals);

    }, 1000); // wait 1000 milliseconds before triggering event.

  });

});

// Always runs first!
function calculateRowTotals(inputQuantity, inputQuantityValue, callback) {

  // DO Something...

  // Here we 

  // Here is where I imagine this would take place...

  if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") {
    callback();
  }

}

function calculateColumnTotals() {

  // reset before calculations...
  materialColumnTotal = 0;
  laborColumnTotal = 0;
  equipmentColumnTotal = 0;
  grandTotal = 0;

  // for each row of table...
  for (let row of tableLineItems.rows) {

    // for each cell of row...
    for(let cell of row.cells) {

      // if cell contains class...
      if(cell.classList.contains('material-cost')) {

        // debug - MAT
        // debug - $/EA

        let materialLineItemCost     = parseFloat(cell.innerText);
        let materialLineItemCostEach = parseFloat(cell.nextElementSibling.innerText);

        // console.log('cellInnerTextMaterial: ', cell.innerText, 'cellInnerTextMaterialEA: ', cell.nextElementSibling.innerText)

        // calculate material column total
        materialColumnTotal += +materialLineItemCost || 0;

      }

      // if cell contains class...
      if(cell.classList.contains('labor-cost')) {

        // debug - LAB
        // debug - $/EA

        let laborLineItemCost     = parseFloat(cell.innerText);
        let laborLineItemCostEach = parseFloat(cell.nextElementSibling.innerText);

        // console.log('cellInnerTextLabor: ', cell.innerText, 'cellInnerTextLaborEA: ', cell.nextElementSibling.innerText)

        // calculate labor column total
        laborColumnTotal += +laborLineItemCost || 0;

      }

      // if cell contains class...
      if(cell.classList.contains('equipment-cost')) {

        // debug - EQP
        // debug - $/EA

        let equipmentLineItemCost     = parseFloat(cell.innerText);
        let equipmentLineItemCostEach = parseFloat(cell.nextElementSibling.innerText);

        // console.log('cellInnerTextEquipment: ', cell.innerText, 'cellInnerTextEquipmentEA: ', cell.nextElementSibling.innerText)

        // calculate equipment column total
        equipmentColumnTotal += +equipmentLineItemCost || 0;

      }

    }

  }

  // debug - column totals
  // console.log('materialColumnTotal: ', materialColumnTotal);
  // console.log('laborColumnTotal: ', laborColumnTotal);
  // console.log('equipmentColumnTotal: ', equipmentColumnTotal);

  // grand total...
  grandTotal = materialColumnTotal + laborColumnTotal + equipmentColumnTotal;

  document.getElementsByClassName("material-column-total")[0].innerText = materialColumnTotal.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementsByClassName("labor-column-total")[0].innerText = laborColumnTotal.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementsByClassName("equipment-column-total")[0].innerText = equipmentColumnTotal.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementsByClassName("grand-total")[0].innerText = grandTotal.toFixed(2);

}
```

```css
body { 
  font-family: 'Montserrat', monospace;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1rem;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

table {

  width: 675px;

}

/* QTY */
table th:nth-child(1) {
  width: 75px;
  text-align: center;
}
/* UNIT */
table th:nth-child(2) {
  width: 75px;
  text-align: center;
}
/* MAT */
table th:nth-child(3) {
  width: 75px;
  text-align: right;
}
/* $/EA */
table th:nth-child(4) {
  width: 75px;
  text-align: left;
}
/* LAB */
table th:nth-child(5) {
  width: 75px;
  text-align: right;
}
/* $/EA */
table th:nth-child(6) {
  width: 75px;
  text-align: left;
}
/* EQP */
table th:nth-child(7) {
  width: 75px;
  text-align: right;
}
/* $/EA */
table th:nth-child(8) {
  width: 75px;
  text-align: left;
}
/* TTL */
table th:nth-child(9) {
  width: 75px;
  text-align: right;
}

/* QTY */
table td:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: center;
}
/* UNIT */
table td:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: center;
}
/* MAT */
table td:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: right;
}
/* $/EA */
table td:nth-child(4) {
  text-align: left;
}
/* LAB */
table td:nth-child(5) {
  text-align: right;
}
/* $/EA */
table td:nth-child(6) {
  text-align: left;
}
/* EQP */
table td:nth-child(7) {
  text-align: right;
}
/* $/EA */
table td:nth-child(8) {
  text-align: left;
}
/* TTL */
table td:nth-child(9) {
  text-align: right;
}


.cell-bg-blue {
  background-color: #e3f2fd;
}

.cell-text-blue {
  color: #1976d2;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" id="tableLineItems">

<thead>

  <th>QTY</th>
  <th>UNIT</th>
  <th>MAT</th>
  <th>$/EA</th>
  <th>LAB</th>
  <th>$/EA</th>
  <th>EQP</th>
  <th>$/EA</th>
  <th>TTL</th>

</thead>

<tbody>

  <tr>
    <td class="input-quantity cell-bg-blue" contenteditable="true">0</td>
    <td class="static-unit">SF</td>
    <td class="material-cost">1.00</td>
    <td class="material-cost-each">0.99</td>
    <td class="labor-cost">2.00</td>
    <td class="labor-cost-each">0.99</td>
    <td class="equipment-cost">3.00</td>
    <td class="equipment-cost-each">0.99</td>
    <th class="line-item-subtotal">0.00</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="input-quantity cell-bg-blue" contenteditable="true">0</td>
    <td class="static-unit">SF</td>
    <td class="material-cost">1.00</td>
    <td class="material-cost-each">0.99</td>
    <td class="labor-cost">2.00</td>
    <td class="labor-cost-each">0.99</td>
    <td class="equipment-cost">3.00</td>
    <td class="equipment-cost-each">0.99</td>
    <th class="line-item-subtotal">0.00</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="input-quantity cell-bg-blue" contenteditable="true">0</td>
    <td class="static-unit">SF</td>
    <td class="material-cost">1.00</td>
    <td class="material-cost-each">0.99</td>
    <td class="labor-cost">2.00</td>
    <td class="labor-cost-each">0.99</td>
    <td class="equipment-cost">3.00</td>
    <td class="equipment-cost-each">0.99</td>
    <th class="line-item-subtotal">0.00</th>
  </tr>

</tbody>

<thead>

  <th>&nbsp;</th>
  <th>&nbsp;</th>
  <th class="material-column-total">0.00</th>
  <th>&nbsp;</th>
  <th class="labor-column-total">0.00</th>
  <th>&nbsp;</th>
  <th class="equipment-column-total">0.00</th>
  <th>&nbsp;</th>
  <th class="grand-total cell-text-blue">0.00</th>

</thead>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take on your question in the spirit: "write less, do more!".

As the structure of your table is quite regular there is not really a need for all the class attributes on the `<td>` elements.

Without it the code can be shortened siginificantly to the following:

```js
// helper function:
const qsa=(s,o)=>[...(o||document).querySelectorAll(s)];
qsa('#tableLineItems tr td:first-child')
  .forEach(td=>{td.contentEditable=true;
                td.addEventListener('keyup',updateAll)});
  
function updateAll(ev){
  // First, update current row:
  var cr=ev.target.parentNode,
      tds=cr.childNodes,
      qty=parseInt(tds[0].innerText);
  for (var v,sum=0,j=2;  j<8;  j+=2,sum+=v){
    v=qty*tds[j+1].innerText;
    tds[j].innerText=(v).toFixed(2);
  }
  tds[8].innerText=sum.toFixed(2);
  
  // Next, sum up all the columns:
  var ths=qsa('th',qsa('#tableLineItems thead')[1]);
  for (j=3; j<10; j+=2) {
    sum=qsa('tr :nth-child('+j+')',cr.parentNode)
        .reduce((a,td)=>+td.innerText+a, 0);
    ths[j-1].innerText=sum.toFixed(2);
  }
 }
```

```css
td:first-child {background: #ccccff}
```

```html
<table border="1" id="tableLineItems">
<thead><tr>
  <th>QTY</th><th>UNIT</th><th>MAT</th><th>$/EA</th><th>LAB</th><th>$/EA</th>
  <th>EQP</th><th>$/EA</th><th>TTL</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>0</td><td>SF0</td><td>0.00</td><td>0.99</td><td>0.00</td><td>0.99</td><td>0.00</td><td>0.99</td><th>0.00</th></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>SF1</td><td>0.00</td><td>2.99</td><td>0.00</td><td>5.99</td><td>0.00</td><td>0.99</td><th>0.00</th></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>SF2</td><td>0.00</td><td>0.69</td><td>0.00</td><td>0.99</td><td>0.00</td><td>0.99</td><th>0.00</th></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>SF3</td><td>0.00</td><td>1.99</td><td>0.00</td><td>0.99</td><td>0.00</td><td>0.49</td><th>0.00</th></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>SF4</td><td>0.00</td><td>0.99</td><td>0.00</td><td>1.99</td><td>0.00</td><td>0.99</td><th>0.00</th></tr>
</tbody>
<thead><tr>
  <th>sums:</th><th>&nbsp;</th><th>0.00</th>
  <th>&nbsp;</th><th>0.00</th><th>&nbsp;</th>
  <th>0.00</th><th>&nbsp;</th>
  <th>0.00</th>
</tr></thead>
</table>
```

Please note: `qsa()` is a little helper function. It is a shortcut to the methods `document.querySelectorAll()` or `element.querySelectorAll()` (depending on the scond optional argument) with the "little" difference that it always returns an array.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. After some parent & child node research I have come up with a solution.

I have basically debuged the parent `tr` of inputQuantity `td` cell. I then access each by index. I then updated the function below to reference each respective table cell in the current row I need to calculate.

**The Aproach**

[image: sample2]

**The solution**

```
// Always runs first!
function calculateRowTotals(inputQuantity, inputQuantityValue, callback) {

    // DO Something...

    // debug - parent childNodes object...
    // console.log(inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes);

    // index for MAT cell
    console.log('MAT: ', inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[5].innerText);
    // index for $/EA cell
    console.log('$/EA: ', inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[7].innerText);
    // output for MAT
    inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[5].innerText = (parseFloat(inputQuantityValue) * parseFloat(inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[7].innerText)).toFixed(2);


    // index for LAB cell
    console.log('LAB: ', inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[9].innerText);
    // index for $/EA cell
    console.log('$/EA: ', inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[11].innerText);
    // output for MAT
    inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[9].innerText = (parseFloat(inputQuantityValue) * parseFloat(inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[11].innerText)).toFixed(2);


    // index for EQP cell
    console.log('EQP: ', inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[13].innerText);
    // index for $/EA cell
    console.log('$/EA: ', inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[15].innerText);
    // output for EQP
    inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[13].innerText = (parseFloat(inputQuantityValue) * parseFloat(inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[15].innerText)).toFixed(2);


    var lineItemSubTotal = parseFloat(inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[5].innerText) + parseFloat(inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[9].innerText) + parseFloat(inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[13].innerText);
    // index for TTL cell
    console.log('TTL: ', inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[17].innerText);
    // TTL - line item subtotal
    inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[17].innerText = lineItemSubTotal.toFixed(2);


    // proceed to calback...
    if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") {
      callback();
    }

}
```

**The Update. Working.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>TABLE v1.0</title>
<!-- GOOGLE FONT CSS - Montserrat -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- CSS STYLES -->
<style type="text/css">

  body { 
    font-family: 'Montserrat', monospace;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1rem;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
  table {
    width: 675px;
  }
  /* QTY */
  table th:nth-child(1) {
    width: 75px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  /* UNIT */
  table th:nth-child(2) {
    width: 75px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  /* MAT */
  table th:nth-child(3) {
    width: 75px;
    text-align: right;
  }
  /* $/EA */
  table th:nth-child(4) {
    width: 75px;
    text-align: left;
  }
  /* LAB */
  table th:nth-child(5) {
    width: 75px;
    text-align: right;
  }
  /* $/EA */
  table th:nth-child(6) {
    width: 75px;
    text-align: left;
  }
  /* EQP */
  table th:nth-child(7) {
    width: 75px;
    text-align: right;
  }
  /* $/EA */
  table th:nth-child(8) {
    width: 75px;
    text-align: left;
  }
  /* TTL */
  table th:nth-child(9) {
    width: 75px;
    text-align: right;
  }

  /* QTY */
  table td:nth-child(1) {
    text-align: center;
  }
  /* UNIT */
  table td:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: center;
  }
  /* MAT */
  table td:nth-child(3) {
    text-align: right;
  }
  /* $/EA */
  table td:nth-child(4) {
    text-align: left;
  }
  /* LAB */
  table td:nth-child(5) {
    text-align: right;
  }
  /* $/EA */
  table td:nth-child(6) {
    text-align: left;
  }
  /* EQP */
  table td:nth-child(7) {
    text-align: right;
  }
  /* $/EA */
  table td:nth-child(8) {
    text-align: left;
  }
  /* TTL */
  table td:nth-child(9) {
    text-align: right;
  }
  .cell-bg-blue {
    background-color: #e3f2fd;
  }
  .cell-text-blue {
    color: #1976d2;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>


<table border="1" id="tableLineItems">

  <thead>

    <th>QTY</th>
    <th>UNIT</th>
    <th>MAT</th>
    <th>$/EA</th>
    <th>LAB</th>
    <th>$/EA</th>
    <th>EQP</th>
    <th>$/EA</th>
    <th>TTL</th>

  </thead>

  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td class="input-quantity cell-bg-blue" contenteditable="true">0</td>
      <td class="static-unit">SF</td>
      <td class="material-cost">0.00</td>
      <td class="material-cost-each">0.99</td>
      <td class="labor-cost">0.00</td>
      <td class="labor-cost-each">0.99</td>
      <td class="equipment-cost">0.00</td>
      <td class="equipment-cost-each">0.99</td>
      <th class="line-item-subtotal">0.00</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="input-quantity cell-bg-blue" contenteditable="true">0</td>
      <td class="static-unit">SF</td>
      <td class="material-cost">0.00</td>
      <td class="material-cost-each">0.99</td>
      <td class="labor-cost">0.00</td>
      <td class="labor-cost-each">0.99</td>
      <td class="equipment-cost">0.00</td>
      <td class="equipment-cost-each">0.99</td>
      <th class="line-item-subtotal">0.00</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="input-quantity cell-bg-blue" contenteditable="true">0</td>
      <td class="static-unit">SF</td>
      <td class="material-cost">0.00</td>
      <td class="material-cost-each">0.99</td>
      <td class="labor-cost">0.00</td>
      <td class="labor-cost-each">0.99</td>
      <td class="equipment-cost">0.00</td>
      <td class="equipment-cost-each">0.99</td>
      <th class="line-item-subtotal">0.00</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="input-quantity cell-bg-blue" contenteditable="true">0</td>
      <td class="static-unit">SF</td>
      <td class="material-cost">0.00</td>
      <td class="material-cost-each">0.99</td>
      <td class="labor-cost">0.00</td>
      <td class="labor-cost-each">0.99</td>
      <td class="equipment-cost">0.00</td>
      <td class="equipment-cost-each">0.99</td>
      <th class="line-item-subtotal">0.00</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="input-quantity cell-bg-blue" contenteditable="true">0</td>
      <td class="static-unit">SF</td>
      <td class="material-cost">0.00</td>
      <td class="material-cost-each">0.99</td>
      <td class="labor-cost">0.00</td>
      <td class="labor-cost-each">0.99</td>
      <td class="equipment-cost">0.00</td>
      <td class="equipment-cost-each">0.99</td>
      <th class="line-item-subtotal">0.00</th>
    </tr>

  </tbody>

  <thead>

    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th class="material-column-total">0.00</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th class="labor-column-total">0.00</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th class="equipment-column-total">0.00</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th class="grand-total cell-text-blue">0.00</th>

  </thead>

</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

  // Local Scripts begin here.

  // reference to table
  var tableLineItems = document.getElementById('tableLineItems');

  // global variables...
  var materialColumnTotal = 0;
  var laborColumnTotal = 0;
  var equipmentColumnTotal = 0;
  var grandTotal = 0;

  // Create global keyupTimer1 outside keyup scope.
  var keyupTimer1;

  // Call querySelectorAll() on all elements with a specific class, then use forEach() to iterate on them:
  document.querySelectorAll('.input-quantity').forEach(cell => {
    // add event listeners...
    cell.addEventListener('keyup', event => {

      // console.log('keyup event works.');

      if (keyupTimer1) {
        // Reset keyupTimer1 and abort function call.
        clearTimeout(keyupTimer1);
      }
      // Set keyupTimer1 to tick in 1 second for 1 seconds then call function and stop.
      keyupTimer1 = setTimeout(function (event) {
        // debug
        // console.log('keyupTimer1 works.');

        var inputQuantity = cell;
        var inputQuantityValue = parseFloat(cell.innerText);

        // debug - QTY
        // console.log('cellInnerTextQuantity: ', inputQuantityValue);

        // handle keyup event
        calculateRowTotals(inputQuantity, inputQuantityValue, calculateColumnTotals);

      }, 1000); // wait 1000 milliseconds before triggering event.

    });

  });

  // Always runs first!
  function calculateRowTotals(inputQuantity, inputQuantityValue, callback) {

    // DO Something...

    // debug - parent childNodes object...
    // console.log(inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes);

    // index for MAT cell
    // console.log('MAT: ', inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[5].innerText);
    // index for $/EA cell
    // console.log('$/EA: ', inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[7].innerText);
    // output for MAT
    inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[5].innerText = (parseFloat(inputQuantityValue) * parseFloat(inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[7].innerText)).toFixed(2);


    // index for LAB cell
    // console.log('LAB: ', inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[9].innerText);
    // index for $/EA cell
    // console.log('$/EA: ', inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[11].innerText);
    // output for MAT
    inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[9].innerText = (parseFloat(inputQuantityValue) * parseFloat(inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[11].innerText)).toFixed(2);


    // index for EQP cell
    // console.log('EQP: ', inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[13].innerText);
    // index for $/EA cell
    // console.log('$/EA: ', inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[15].innerText);
    // output for EQP
    inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[13].innerText = (parseFloat(inputQuantityValue) * parseFloat(inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[15].innerText)).toFixed(2);


    var lineItemSubTotal = parseFloat(inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[5].innerText) + parseFloat(inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[9].innerText) + parseFloat(inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[13].innerText);
    // index for TTL cell
    // console.log('TTL: ', inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[17].innerText);
    // TTL - line item subtotal
    inputQuantity.parentNode.childNodes[17].innerText = lineItemSubTotal.toFixed(2);


    // proceed to calback...
    if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") {
      callback();
    }

  }

  function calculateColumnTotals() {

    // reset before calculations...
    materialColumnTotal = 0;
    laborColumnTotal = 0;
    equipmentColumnTotal = 0;
    grandTotal = 0;

    // for each row of table...
    for (let row of tableLineItems.rows) {

      // for each cell of row...
      for(let cell of row.cells) {

        // if cell contains class...
        if(cell.classList.contains('material-cost')) {

          // debug - MAT
          // debug - $/EA

          let materialLineItemCost     = parseFloat(cell.innerText);
          let materialLineItemCostEach = parseFloat(cell.nextElementSibling.innerText);

          // console.log('cellInnerTextMaterial: ', cell.innerText, 'cellInnerTextMaterialEA: ', cell.nextElementSibling.innerText)

          // calculate material column total
          materialColumnTotal += +materialLineItemCost || 0;

        }

        // if cell contains class...
        if(cell.classList.contains('labor-cost')) {

          // debug - LAB
          // debug - $/EA

          let laborLineItemCost     = parseFloat(cell.innerText);
          let laborLineItemCostEach = parseFloat(cell.nextElementSibling.innerText);

          // console.log('cellInnerTextLabor: ', cell.innerText, 'cellInnerTextLaborEA: ', cell.nextElementSibling.innerText)

          // calculate labor column total
          laborColumnTotal += +laborLineItemCost || 0;

        }

        // if cell contains class...
        if(cell.classList.contains('equipment-cost')) {

          // debug - EQP
          // debug - $/EA

          let equipmentLineItemCost     = parseFloat(cell.innerText);
          let equipmentLineItemCostEach = parseFloat(cell.nextElementSibling.innerText);

          // console.log('cellInnerTextEquipment: ', cell.innerText, 'cellInnerTextEquipmentEA: ', cell.nextElementSibling.innerText)

          // calculate equipment column total
          equipmentColumnTotal += +equipmentLineItemCost || 0;

        }

      }

    }

    // debug - column totals
    // console.log('materialColumnTotal: ', materialColumnTotal);
    // console.log('laborColumnTotal: ', laborColumnTotal);
    // console.log('equipmentColumnTotal: ', equipmentColumnTotal);

    // grand total...
    grandTotal = materialColumnTotal + laborColumnTotal + equipmentColumnTotal;

    document.getElementsByClassName("material-column-total")[0].innerText = materialColumnTotal.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementsByClassName("labor-column-total")[0].innerText = laborColumnTotal.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementsByClassName("equipment-column-total")[0].innerText = equipmentColumnTotal.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementsByClassName("grand-total")[0].innerText = grandTotal.toFixed(2);

  }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```